# PHP - mysqli_select_db not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am switching from MySQL to MySQLi and I am upon an error which i Google and was unable to solve. The problem is with the selection (mysqli_select_db) of the database which was okay prior to the transition where i was using (mysql_select_db). Hope your can help me solve this problem.

**UPDATE - MY CURRENT CODE**

```
        <?php
        $submit = $_POST['submit'];
        //form data
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $name2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name2']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);
        $phone2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['phone2']);
        $email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email2']);
        $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
        $address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address2']);
        $address3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address3']);
        $address4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address4']);
        if ($submit) {
            //connect database
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Passw0rd", "logindb") or die ("Connection Error");
            //namecheck
            $namecheck = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'");
            //check for existance
            if($name&&$name2&&$email&&$password&&$password2&&$phone2&&$email2&&$address&&$address2&&$address3&&$address4) {
                if(strlen($password)<8) {
                    echo "Password must be least 8 characters";
                }
                if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$password)) {
                    echo "Password must have at least 1 upper case characters";
                }
                if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
                    echo "Password must have at least 1 number";
                }
                if(!preg_match("#[\W]+#",$password)) {
                    echo "Password must have at least 1 symbol";
                }
                if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password']) {
                    echo "Password does not match";
                }
                if($_POST['email2'] == $_POST['email']) {
                    echo "Secondary email must not be the same as Email";
                }
                //encrypt password
                $password = sha1($password);
                $password2 = sha1($password2);
                //generate random code
                $random = rand(11111111,99999999);
                if(isset($error)&&!empty($error)) {
                    implode($error);
                }
                else
                {
                    //register the user
                    $register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$name2','$email','$password','$password2','$phone2','$email2','$address','$address2','$address3','$address4','$random','0')");
                    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=Activate.php?id=$lastid&code=$random'>";
                    die ();
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: try - mysqli_select_db($connect, "logindb") or die("Selection Error");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick complete solution

```
   <?php
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    //connect database
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Passw0rd") or die ("Connection Error");
    //select database
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "logindb") or die("Selection Error");

    //form data
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
    $name2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name2']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password2']);
    $phone2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['phone2']);
    $email2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email2']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['address']);
    $address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['address2']);
    $address3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['address3']);
    $address4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['address4']);
    if ($submit) {
        //namecheck
        $namecheck = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($namecheck);
        if(strlen($email)<5) {
            echo "Email must have at least 5 characters";
        }
        else
        {
            if($count==0) {
            }
            else
            {
                if($count==1) {
                    echo "User already Exists";
                }
            }
        }
        //check for existance
        if($name&&$name2&&$email&&$password&&$password2&&$phone2&&$email2&&$address&&$address2&&$address3&&$address4) {
            if(strlen($password)<8) {
                echo "Password must be least 8 characters";
            }
            if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#",$password)) {
                echo "Password must have at least 1 upper case characters";
            }
            if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
                echo "Password must have at least 1 number";
            }
            if(!preg_match("#[\W]+#",$password)) {
                echo "Password must have at least 1 symbol";
            }
            if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password']) {
                echo "Password does not match";
            }
            if($_POST['email2'] == $_POST['email']) {
                echo "Secondary email must not be the same as Email";
            }
            //encrypt password
            $password = sha1($password);
            $password2 = sha1($password2);
            //generate random code
            $random = rand(11111111,99999999);
            if(isset($error)&&!empty($error)) {
                implode($error);
            }
            else
            {
                //register the user
                $register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$name2','$email','$password','$password2','$phone2','$email2','$address','$address2','$address3','$address4','$random','0')");
                $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=Activate.php?id=$lastid&code=$random'>";
                die ();
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

You also have to write fields after table name on line 70 `$register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users` and before values `VALUES (` like example below.

```
INSERT INTO users(username,userpass,name,email,userrole,joined,userstatus) VALUES('$username','$userpass','$name','$email','$userrole','$joined','$userstatus')
```

Replace you line #70 with the following one

```
$register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users(name,name2,email,password,password2,phone2,email2,address,address2,address3,address4,random,active) VALUES ('$name','$name2','$email','$password','$password2','$phone2','$email2','$address','$address2','$address3','$address4','$random','0')");
```

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: @JialeLeong What is error?

Comment: there is no error, i clicked submit and the page just refresh and no data is inserted to the db

Comment: @JialeLeong I have updated my answer. You must enter field names in query and in example above.

Comment: Tried your updated coding but still not working

Comment: @JialeLeong you do not understand. You have to write the name of your db table's column name into your insert query. OK let me know the name of columns you have in table `users`

Comment: my db table's column have the same name as the variables

Comment: @JialeLeong Why the first value is empty in values? hint `VALUES ('','$name'`

Comment: the first value is id which is a INT, PRIMARY KEY and AUTO INCREMENTAL

Comment: @JialeLeong Why you using these `,'$random','0'` what is the name of field of them?

Comment: *"there is no error..."* - Because you're assuming success without even taking failure into consideration. What I mean by this is, you're not checking for errors either on the PHP or the query (MySQL) side of things. @JialeLeong

Comment: @JialeLeong I have updated my answer again.

Comment: @DJ MHA the $random and '0' is for activated purpose and their field are random and active in the db table column.

Comment: @JialeLeong I have updated my answer again and write random and active fields and value at last replacement in my answer.

Comment: @JialeLeong I'm glad to know it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

pass `connection` ref in 1st param in `mysqli_select_db()` function, try this

```
mysqli_select_db($connect, "logindb") or die("Selection Error");
```

and also in `mysqli_query($connect, "query here")`

**UPDATE** all `mysqli_*` functions required connection ref except result functions

Comment: You're missing something. Hint: `mysqli_real_escape_string` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: is it possible you point our what is the coding that i am missing

Comment: @Fred-ii- all `mysqii_*` functions required connection `ref` except result functions

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? Are you saying that `mysqli_real_escape_string` doesn't need DB connection? You haven't made any mention of that in your answer.

Comment: result functions means `mysqli_num_rows()`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` etc,